# What makes an extrudeur different from an extrudeuse?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, genre

I see the words "extrudeur" and "extrudeuse" used to describe very similar equipment, typically both corresponding to "extruder" in English. One of my 3D printer instructions lists the specs as follows:

> Type d’extrudeur: Extrudeuse

There must be a nuance although dictionaries have similar definitions for both. What is the difference between "un extrudeur" and "une extrudeuse"?

Answer (score 3):

It's a weird thing about French where both -eur and -euse are found for tools, but there *is a distinction in their use* (although I really wouldn't be able to speculate on the etymological origins!): a word in *-eur* for an object is generally going to be for something that is more-or-less hand-operated, that is a tool or instrument, but a word in *-euse* is likely going to be powered, some sort machine. A *batteur* à oeuf is an eggbeater, but a *batteuse* (e.g. in *moisonneuse-batteuse*) is a [threshing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshing_machine).

For the particular situation you ran into, it's completely impossible to tell what's going on without seeing what I assume is an English original formulation that got mangled in translation (not an uncommon situation!).

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think I have seen extrudeuse used for bigger-scale, more industrial contexts. Maybe.